# Search for a regex in a string of a TV Show filename

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to test if a filename has a season and episod number, so far so bad:

```
for f in "${folderToClean}"/*.mkv
do
  filenameWithoutExtension=`basename "${f%.*}"`
  echo "$filenameWithoutExtension file..."

  if [[ "$filenameWithoutExtension" =~ [sS][\d]+[Ee][\d]+ ]]; then
    echo 'pouet'
  fi
done
```

For filenames like `My.TV.show.S01E02.1080p.mkv`, I don't get any result… Oh boy I hate regex so much…

Comment: Check out RegExr, you may find it helpful for developing regex patterns https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[[ ... ]]` does not know `\d`.

Replace

```
[sS][\d]+[Ee][\d]+
```

with

```
[sS][0-9]+[Ee][0-9]+
```

Comment: Thanks ! It worked ! Do you know a tool like regex101 who could help me test regex within [[ ]] by any chances ?

Comment: I'll have to pass. Right of `=~` is considered an extended regular expression.

Comment: And do you know if it would be possible to capture the string before (and not including) the regex result ?

Comment: This? `[[ "My.TV.show.S01E02.1080p" =~ (.*)[sS][0-9]+[Ee][0-9]+ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"`